# My hp elitebook folio 9470m is Stuck on “reset system” boot loop after successfully installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My hp elitebook folio 9470m is Stuck on “reset system” boot loop after successfully installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10..

I used boot-repair to generate this report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MXTjzjzb9T/

Kindly help

Comment: Would be better if you can edit the post and add image again, nothing is found on paste.